# Swift extension for Dictionary. Error 'Cannot invoke 'dataWithJSONObject'

Tags: ios, swift, dictionary, compiler-errors

I am newbie in swift. I have stuck in creating extension for Dictionary. 
My extension is:

```
extension Dictionary {
    var JSONString: String {
        var error: NSError?
        var jsonData: NSData? = NSJSONSerialization.dataWithJSONObject(self, options: NSJSONWritingOptions.PrettyPrinted, error: &error)
        if error == nil {
            return NSString(data: jsonData!, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding) as! String
        }
        return ""
    }        
}
```

I get an error message

> Cannot invoke ‘dataWithJSONObject’ with an argument of type ‘(Dictionary , options:NSJSONWritingOptions, error: inout NSError?)’

Can anybody help me to resolve this problem?

Comment: What is the goal, what do you want to achieve? Please give some context.

Comment: I want to create a method (in extension) to convert Dictionary to JSON string. I have a category on obj-c:

Comment: Have a look at http://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/87251/68030

Comment: <code>- (NSString *)jsonString {
    NSError *error;
    NSData *jsonData = [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:self
                                                       options:NSJSONWritingPrettyPrinted // Pass 0 if you don't care about the readability of the generated string
                                                         error:&error];
    if (error == nil) {
        return [[NSString alloc] initWithData:jsonData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    }
    NSAssert(error, @"error");
    return @"";
}</code>

Comment: Can you explain why my code doesn’t work  ? My code is similar...

Answer (score 1):

I have just found a solution and understood my mistake. 
Correct code is

```
extension Dictionary {

var JSONString: String {
    var error: NSError?
    var dictionary: [String: AnyObject] = [:]

    for (key, value) in self {
        dictionary["\(key)"] = "\(value)"
    }

    var jsonData: NSData = NSJSONSerialization.dataWithJSONObject(dictionary, options: NSJSONWritingOptions.PrettyPrinted, error: &error)!
    if error == nil {
        return NSString(data: jsonData, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)! as String
    }
    return ""
}
```

}

Thank you all